# "New email address format" button in Exchange 2013 on Windows 2012 R2 does nothing

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

I've set up an Exchange mailserver on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine, but I'd like to add another domain to the mail settings. So at the Accepted domains page I've added the domain for which I'd like to receive mail and set that one to default.  The problem begins when I try to move the domain from the default installed domain (the AD domain which I don't want) to the domain that I do want:

The domain I don't want is referenced by the Default Email Address Policy, but I can't seem to change it or add another domain to the list because when I click the + button for new email address policy, I get the following screen fine, but when I actually try to add the new email address format, I don't get a new screen or anything. Screenshot https://s15.postimg.org/us1sg4cdn/newpolicy.jpg

What am I missing/doing wrong?

This problem exists using both Mozilla Firefox 49.0.1 and Google Chrome Version 53.0.2785.143 m (64-bit)

Comment: Addition: FYI I did not update either the OS or the Exchange mail program because that screwed up the Authentication mechanisms (Windows Authentication, Forms Authentication, Digest etc), and it had cost me too much effort to work those out so I thought I'd reset and go from scratch again and maybe update it once the config is finished.

Answer (score 0):

The default domain policy shouldn't be touched and you need to leave it alone. The domain will usually match your internal Windows domain and is required for Exchange to work correctly.

Thus you should create a new email address policy with your preferred domain listed. This will have a higher priority than the default (which is always the lowest) so users will get the email address in that domain.

Finally - which version of Exchange 2013 do you have? Older CUs have issues with non Microsoft browsers. If you haven't already you should update Exchange to the latest CU. If it is causing you problems with authentication then that needs to be handled separately, but Exchange needs to be kept up to date.

Comment: I've updated the Exchange 2013 to CU 14, and now I can't get back into the ECP (blank screen after login), so I'll deal with that first, then I'll get back to you when I solved it. (already tried http://superuser.com/questions/737399/microsft-exchange-2013-on-server-2012-owa-shows-blank-page?answertab=active#tab-top but that didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I can get back into the Admin Panel again after the update BUT after doing some digging in the Event Viewer I saw the following errors at login time:

The Microsoft Exchange Replication service failed to start the TCP listener. Error: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions I fixed this by running these in PowerShell and then restarting:  Remove-NetIPAddress + netsh winsock reset.

Now the original error has been resolved but I'm getting a new one.

I'm going to open up another thread for the new error.