# exchange 2013 email address policy SMTP blank screen

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, exchange-2013

Continuation of ["New email address format" button in Exchange 2013 on Windows 2012 R2 does nothing](https://serverfault.com/questions/807185/new-email-address-format-button-in-exchange-2013-on-windows-2012-r2-does-nothi/808127#808127).

The + button (referenced in other question) works, but when I add a new format, it does not appear in the SMTP list/row:

[image]

The problem is the empty Email Address Format box which won't allow me to save the new policy.

The policy I am trying to create is:

[image]

I am running Exchange 2013 (CU 14) on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The solution eventually was to use IE to add the policy.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be doing it wrong.

If you want an additional custom domain use the "Specify a custom domain name for the email address" radio button near the top.

If you really want a "custom address type" then the "Email Address Parameters" portion needs to have a variable before the "@" in "@ziggo.nl".  Something like the example callout, where you specify things like surname, etc.

You can't just have the domain itself in a custom address type, so if all you want is to have a secondary custom domain, select it as stated near the top...or use the drop down for an accepted domain if this domain is in that list.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have followed your steps and I'm still getting the error which is shown in the first screenshot (SMTP field is blank and won't let me save, gives the error "The address 'SMTP:undefined' is invalid: The SMTP e-mail address template "undefined" is invalid."

This happens with whatever I input in the second screenshot (my way and the ways you suggested). All give the same result.